# Block direct access to thank you pages

Tags: customization, redirect

I have parent pages which are downloadable resources. On these pages, people will fill in a form and then be redirected to a thank you page.

The thank you pages are child pages.

I would like to block direct access to those child pages and only allow access if people were redirected from the parent pages.

I found some code online but this would means that I need to edit this code for every resource I add. I would like to code to only allow access if redirected from the parent page.

How can I achieve this?

```
function wpse15677455_redirect() {
$ref = wp_get_referer();
if (is_page(1911) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact"){
   wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
}
else if(is_page(1269) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact-form-2"){
    wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
}
else if(is_page(1825) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact-form-3"){
    wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
}
else if(is_page(1623) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact-form-4"){
    wp_redirect( get_home_url() ); exit();
```

};

Comment: I would not use a redirect.  I would use Java to unhide a "Thank You" div already in place hiding at the bottom of the page.  Using Java to pop things up or hide/unhide things is very fast.  And you can embed variables on the page that it reads and then behaves how you want it to.

Comment: @Elkrat The point is to keep the child page content secure though, and only available to people who have submitted the form, and embedding the child page content on the page to display in the popup would be let people find it without filling in the form. Fast isn't the issue.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood. But I stand by the opinion that redirection is probably not the best choice of architecture. What I actually do for a video library at work is to have my logged in user click a link so jquery can create a form and submit it to a popup window.  The popup window takes the name in post data and looks up the current randomized name, then embeds <video> tags with that name.  The client has the correct video name if they go to the trouble of examining post data, but it's only good until the cron job randomizes the names at midnight and rewrites the table.